# Thread with the lowest priority is invoked more times

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, task-parallel-library, thread-priority

The following code 5 threads with different priorities are competing for access to the CPU with 8 cores (Mac OS X 10.8.5, Mono). Each thread increases its counter.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

      class PriorityTesting 
     { 
       static long[] counts; 
       static bool finish;

       static void ThreadFunc(object iThread) 
       { 
         while(true) 
         { 
           if(finish) 
              break; 
           counts[(int)iThread]++; 
         } 
       }

       static void Main() 
       { 
         counts = new long[5]; 
         Thread[] t = new Thread[5]; 
         for(int i=0; i<t.Length; i++)  
         { 
           t[i] = new Thread(ThreadFunc); 
           t[i].Priority = (ThreadPriority)i; 
         } 
         // Запускаем потоки 
         for(int i=0; i<t.Length; i++) 
           t[i].Start(i);

         // Даём потокам возможность поработать 10 c 
         Thread.Sleep(10000);

         // Сигнал о завершении 
         finish = true;

         // Ожидаем завершения всех потоков 
         for(int i=0; i<t.Length; i++) 
           t[i].Join(); 
         // Вывод результатов 
         for(int i=0; i<t.Length; i++) 
           Console.WriteLine("Thread with priority {0, 15}, Counts: {1}", (ThreadPriority)i, counts[i]); 
       }   
     }
```

Compilation:

```
$ mcs PriorityTesting.cs
$ mono PriorityTesting.exe
```

Output:

```
Thread with priority          Lowest, Counts: 178544880
Thread with priority     BelowNormal, Counts: 167783608
Thread with priority          Normal, Counts: 160593225
Thread with priority     AboveNormal, Counts: 79123315
Thread with priority         Highest, Counts: 81623159
```

How is it that the thread with the lowest priority is invoked more times than threads with the highest priority?

**UPD:**

The same code on the CPU with 2 cores gives (Windows, .NET):

```
 Thread with priority         Lowest, Counts:    7608195 
 Thread with priority    BelowNormal, Counts:   10457706 
 Thread with priority         Normal, Counts:   17852629 
 Thread with priority    AboveNormal, Counts:  297729812 
 Thread with priority        Highest, Counts:  302506232
```

Why the difference?

Comment: Do you notice different behavior if you fix the code so that the `finish` variable is marked `volatile` (as it should be)? I'm grasping at straws of course, but it _might_ make a difference, depending on what hardware you're running this on.

Comment: I would change somehow `ThreadFunc` to give a better chance of switching threads like Thread.Yield or Console.WriteLine... Maybe because of so fast loop, results are distorted.

Comment: Which operating system you have tested?

Comment: After running this in different ways Win7x64-I7-950 (debug/release/cmd-line/msvsdev) the results are that; this code can produce unexpected results in the MS .Net runtime also (see below answers for possible reasons).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Priority` support is not implemented in Mono, so the behaviour you're seeing about the Lowest one being invoked more times may be mere luck.

There's a pull request from a contributor implementing this property, in github, so you may want to join him in asking for a review for it.

**UPDATE**: This answer may be outdated. As Mono advances rapidly, it's better that you re-test your program, maybe Priority works nowadays.

Comment: This seems to be correct. Just tested the code and on a win7 machine with MS.Net runtime it produces the expected results (low prio-lowest count, high-prio highest count).

Comment: @MarvinSmit did you run in release or debug?  I still get very high value for the lowest priority when compiled for release.  Other four are close but still not perfect ordering.  CPU capabilities would also be a factor (core/logical thread count).

Comment: Update: After more testing, the OP's code also does not work correctly using .Net on Win7 (MS version)

Answer (score 3):

This could happen for lots of reasons.

There is something called "Priority Boost" and which is one of them, operating system will boost the priority(increase the priority of threads temporarily) for various reasons Example: A thread has just received an event signal, It is the UI thread which pumps for the messages and there is a new message received in its queue, another reason could be *starvation*.

Starvation could be the case here. Your low priority threads will not get a chance to execute when there is a higher priority thread which is either ready or currently running. If a thread is starved for a long time, operating system will boost the priority for the thread which is being starved, so that it immediately preempts the running threads and gets a chance to execute which cancels out the starved time.

I've tested in windows, results are pretty same and here's the explanation. Operating system gives the boost to starved threads out of pity. I guess something like this exist in other operating systems also.

> Windows has a service called the balance set manager. It runs
>   asynchronously on a system thread looking for starved threads; these
>   are threads that have been waiting to run in the ready state for 4
>   seconds or longer. If it finds one, it will give the thread a
>   temporary priority boost. It always boosts a starved thread's priority
>   to level 1 5, regardless of its current value. This is done to combat
>   starvation, for instance, when many higher priority threads are
>   constantly running such that lower priority threads never get a chance
>   to execute.

Quote from book [Concurrent Programming on Windows-Joe Duffy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X)

**Update:**

As for your updated results in windows OS with 2 cores, yes results are not surprising there is not enough cpu to run the threads which are in ready state, so the operating system has to wait till other threads finishes their *Thread Quantum*. There are enough higher priority threads than lower so obviously operating system gives priority to higher priority threads.

For the results with 8 cores: As noted mono doesn't support priority, you have started the lower priority thread first, and you have enough processors to run the runnable threads. So there is no need to preempt the lower priority threads here. So operating system allows the threads to run without disturbing(preempting). Try to test with more threads than the processor count you have. That is where the priority really comes into picture.

Comment: @downvoter I appreciate the downvote if you can give a reason?

Answer (score 1):

You're starting the lowest priority thread first, escalating to the highest priority.  This gives lower priority threads time to run while the higher priority threads start (starting a thread is not a trivial operation).

Create another boolean flag to regulate counting in the thread function so that all threads have started before any of them begin counting:

```
   static long[] counts; 
   static bool finish;
   static bool count; // add this

   static void ThreadFunc(object iThread) 
   { 
     while(true) 
     { 
       if(finish) 
          break;

       if( count ) // only count when ready
           counts[(int)iThread]++; 
     } 
   }
```

In `Main`:

```
   // After your loop to start the threads
   // set the count flag to start counting
   count = true;
   // Даём потокам возможность поработать 10 c 
   Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

Comment: Missing a volatile for the flag which can lead to very surprising results.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost - don't mess with thread priority. Or process priority. You're not going to help anything, and you'll very likely cause many deadlocks and other synchronization issues as you go along, which will be a lot of *fun* to debug. Trust the OS' thread scheduler to do its job - it's actually pretty good at it!

Second, Mono doesn't support priorities.

Third, you may want to give the threads enough work to actually give them a reason to switch. Five threads on an eight-core CPU aren't going to get enough contention to warrant any thread switches at all, and they might just all run at the same pace. To experiment with thread priorities, you *need* more threads doing work than you have CPU cores. And yes, Hyper-Threaded cores count too.

Don't just do a "stupid" counter - add some silly work for the CPU in each counter step, like `Thread.SpinWait(100000)`. This is going to put some silly stress on the CPU, which will make your counting more interesting and comparable.

I've never seen a good case for changing thread priorities. There's always a better solution, and you're most likely trying to fix a problem that either isn't there, or could be solved in a much better way. A good starter reference for the trouble with priorities is off course Jeff Atwood's http://blog.codinghorror.com/thread-priorities-are-evil/.

Do note that higher-level multi-threading/parallelism constructs like `Task` don't have any way of suggesting a priority or anything like that - there's a good reason for that.

Take care :)